# Download Highcharts graph as image results in weird characters

Tags: printing, download, highcharts, character

I added the "Download graph as image" button to my Highcharts graph. But now I see that the downloaded image version has problems with the non-english characters, such as ä and è. It seems as if a script on the Highcharts-server is being contacted for the production of the image. Anything which could be done there? [Here](http://geodev.grid.unep.ch/megatrends/data/bafu/feinstaub_ch.php?lang=de) is an example of a graph.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have utf-8 encoding on the page, instead of ISO-8859-1

Comment: I tried this out before. But then, the characters are not even displayed correctly on the webpage. Here is the example: http://geodata.grid.unep.ch/megatrends/data/bafu/feinstaub_ch.php?lang=de

Comment: You need to have property encoding of file and in head of webpage. Then you need to replace undefined characters with correct marks.

Comment: Ok, I see. I played around with these before, but didn't find the right combination. Now, it seems that the text-encoding of the code must be in UTF-8. And the metatag in the HTML file should be <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />.